# How could doing the right thing be painful

Tags: word-usage

How could doing the right thing be painful

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, this sounds 100% OK. The sound of the second sentence is a little strange, though. The structure "How could xxxxxxx be so yyyyyyyy?" is usually used when xxxxx and yyyyy sound very different. The first sentence does this just right. But, "taking someone out of the narrative" sounds pretty brutal! Are you killing them? Firing them? I can't tell, but it sounds bad!

If you want to use this sentence structure, find some way to make "taking them out of the narrative" sound less brutal. Maybe "just editing the script" or "promoting the best employee" or whatever you're doing.

Comment: But the grammar is correct, right? the sec one

Comment: Yes, the grammar is correct in both cases.